# how can I split data into multiple columns seperating only after the first colon in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a huge excel list (20k+ rows) and want to split that one column list into multiple columns. 
Previously I used the Data|Text-to-Columns Wizard but it appears to have a limitation: I cannot specify after how many "splits" to stop to split.
Example data:

```
type: abds : das
files: asdfs:jgkd
```

goal is:

```
|type|abds : das|
|files|asdfs:jgkd|
```

thanks for your time :)!

Comment: How about split all columns and then concatenate 2 & 3 back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VBA` is a great tool for small one off tasks like this.

Assuming data is in column `A` and is contiguous from `A1`.  If this is not the case, simply adjust the line `Set rng = ...` to suit your data.

```
Sub SplitColumn()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set rng = Range([a1], [a1].End(xlDown)).Resize(, 2)
    dat = rng
    For i = 1 To UBound(dat, 1)
        j = InStr(dat(i, 1), ":")
        If j > 0 Then
            dat(i, 2) = Mid$(dat(i, 1), j + 1)
            dat(i, 1) = Left$(dat(i, 1), j - 1)
        End If
    Next
    rng = dat
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You could replace the first colon with a "|" - or some other character that won't appear in your data - using:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,":","|",1)
```

Then copy and paste the the results as values and do a Text To Columns on those values.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would write some vbscript to do this task, but if it is a one-column sheet, you could save it as Text (tab-delimited), then open it again. The Excel will ask you what kind of text file is it. Tell it that it is a `file with Separators`, click `Next` and tick `Other` and type a colon in the edit field.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I can think of is to start with what you already did:  the Data|Text-to-Columns Wizard .

You then re-concattenate the fields which were split unintendedly.